# Make a search filter with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is exactly what I want to do:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noth1ng/ytYQd/)

But how can I do this if my html is somewhat more detailed. Cant for the life of me figure it out. So I am making a directory, each entry is:

```
<div class="search">


            <div class='listing' id='recommended' >    
                <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('interactive');">
                <h3>Violet Label</h3>
                <h3>London</h3></a>

                <div id="interactive" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="web"><p><a href="#" onclick="openDeviceBrowser ('http://violetjobs.com')">
                    violetjobs.com</a></p></div>
                    <div class="phone"><p><a href="Tel:07855010244">Tel: 07855010244</a></p></div>
                    <div class="email"><p><a href="mailto:info@violetjobs.com">info@violetjobs.com</a></p></div>

                    <p>Submission Guidelines: None specified</p>
                    <p>Genres: Minimal Tiny Techno, Downbeat Nado House</p>
                </div>  

            </div>
```

I need a search box that filters out as you type. So this one is called Violet Label. As user searches, say pressing 'V' this whole  should remain and others that dont start with V should disappear.

Im sure it is simple!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what's happening in your example -

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){

   //get the current typed text
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    //loop round all the list items
    $('.navList>li').each(function(){

    //find the text in the list item
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

    //show or hide it if the text matches
    (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();

   });
});
```

In your updated example, instead of matching on the text inside the list item, you want to match the content in the `<h3>Violet Label</h3>`. Make this easy to find by adding a class to it - `<h3 class='title'>...</h3>`

You can the loop around each `.listing` and check the title -

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){

   //get the current typed text
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    //loop round all the listings
    $('.listing').each(function(){

    //find the text in the header item
    var text = $(this).find('.title').text().toLowerCase();

    //show or hide it if the text matches
    (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();

   });
});
```

*However* - This is not exceptionally efficient, you would likely be better off looking into some templating libraries, or even a small angular app - filtering is pretty neat there.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. I will look into templating libraries, but just doing this to learn while (trying to) have some fun. So cool of you to help out.